# ttk Image buttons only showing images for last items in collection

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am building a series of mutli-element "buttons" based on a dynamic data set.

I have the list generating and all elements are correctly being placed in their respective TTK elements -- except the logos.   These are *only* appearing in the last multi-element button.

Below is my menu.py file.   I have added a comment about the images in question.

```py
import globals
import os
from data import Data
from utils import Image as imageUtils
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class CreateMenu(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        menuItems = Data.getSchedule().games
        
        

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg = '#000000', width = globals.screenWidth, height = globals.screenHeight)
        self.canvas.pack()
            
        for item in menuItems:
            self.childFrame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, width=(buttonWidth - padding), height=buttonHeight, bg='#888888')

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

            self.awayLogo = imageUtils.webImage(item.away.logo)
            print(self.awayLogo)
            self.awayLogoImageFile = Image.open(self.awayLogo)
            self.awayLogoImageFile = self.awayLogoImageFile.resize((thumbnailWidth - 16, thumbnailHeight - 16), Image.ANTIALIAS) 
            self.awayLogoImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.awayLogoImageFile, format='png', width=thumbnailWidth, height=thumbnailHeight)

            # The image is only getting added in the last instance of "item".  
            # In other items, the cards exist.   
            # I have confirmed that the images exist in the source location.
            # The button below is placed, but is missing the image (except in the last instance of the "item" where it is rendered correctly)

            self.awayLogoButton = ttk.Button(self.childFrame, compound=tk.CENTER, image=self.awayLogoImage, command=lambda link=item.link: selectGame(link))
            self.awayLogoButton.pack(ipady = 1)
            self.awayLogoButton.place(x=0, y=0, width=thumbnailWidth, height=thumbnailHeight)
            
            self.awayNameButton = ttk.Button(self.childFrame, text=item.away.name, command=lambda link=item.link: selectGame(link))
            self.awayNameButton.pack(ipady = 1)
            self.awayNameButton.place(x=thumbnailWidth, y=0, height=buttonHeight/2, width=teamTextWidth)
                
            
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
                    
            self.childFrame.bind("<Return>", lambda event, link=item.link: selectGame(link))
            self.childFrame.focus_set()

            self.childFrame.pack(ipady = 1)
            self.childFrame.place(x = x, y = y)
            
            if (x == (globals.screenWidth - buttonWidth)):
                x = 0
                y = y + buttonHeight
            else:
                x = x + buttonWidth
```

Any ideas on how to correct the images not appearing on all the other instances of `item`?

[image: Example of issue]

Comment: This seems like a lot more code than is necessary to reproduce the problem. For example, there's no reason to call `pack` if you're immediately calling `place` on the net line. It also seems like a lot of the style information isn't necessary to reproduce the problem. Please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve],.

Comment: Can you please simplify the code? Please remove all of the unnecessary code. Also you don't keep a reference to all of your `ImageTk.PhotoImage` objects. That is why they don't appear on your screen

Comment: @TheLizzard I have self.awayLogoImage and self.homeLogoImage?     This follows the same format as all the other elements, which appear.

Comment: Simplified the code.

Comment: @BryanOakley well, you can't use ipady with place.

Comment: @eat-sleep-code How many images and how many variables do you have? The variables you have for the `ImageTk.PhotoImage` objects get overwritten each time the for loop runs. Try putting them in a list

Comment: @TheLizzard ok weird.   Why does this only occur with the images, but not the text?

Comment: @eat-sleep-code When you no longer have a reference to a `ImageTk.PhotoImage`, it gets deleted from tkinter's world. So tkinter can no longer display the image. That is one of tkinter's quirks

Comment: @TheLizzard Tkinter is driving me crazy. :-)   How would I go about fixing that?   The reference issue, not the getting driven crazy part.

Comment: @eat-sleep-code Put all of the `ImageTk.PhotoImage` objects in a list and make sure it is assigned to the class. I would name that list `self.tk_images = []`

Comment: @TheLizzard, not sure I am following.   The loop through menuItems will be the first time I am aware of the images, so can't really feed them into a list before hand?

Comment: @eat-sleep-code: correct: `place` doesn't support `ipady`. I don't understand what point you're trying to make. If you use it with `pack` and then call `place`, all of the `pack` options are thrown out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that python garbage collects all of your images and deletes them from python's memory as soon as you can no longer hold a reference to them.

To fix your issue you will need to add all of the images to a list like this:

```py
self.tk_images = []

for ... in ...:
    tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(...)
    ...
    self.tk_images.append(tk_image)
```

That way you can keep a reference to those images so python doesn't garbage collect them.